# weblogic server installation issue

Tags: java, jdk, oracle-12c

I got my weblogic installation file here:
https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/weblogic/downloads/wls-main-097127.html

I was able to open my Admin command prompt (<kbd>Win key</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>,
type `cmd` and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>).

I was able to execute the jar file in my command prompt using JDK 12 (see picture below).

However I get this error no matter which version of the weblogic I pick:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.1\bin>

java -jar C:\Users\terry\Downloads\fmw_12.2.1.2.0_wls_Disk1_1of1\fmw_12.2.1.2.0_wls.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: com.oracle.cie.common.dao.DataHandlerSpi: com.oracle.cie.common.dao.jaxb.JaxbDataHandlerSpiImpl Unable to get public no-arg constructor
```

[image: Click me to see screen shot]

Comment: Welcome. For purposes of searchability please put the essential parts of the error in the text of your question.

Answer (score 1):

Your Version of the JDK doesn't support your WebLogic, downgrade your JDK version to 8 and try it again.

Comment: Hi @javaPro, could you add a reference to back up your assertion?